# Index of maximum value of each row of an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `Pr`. I want to print index of maximum value of each row. For example, for row `0`, the maximum value is `1.72731864e+003` and it occurs at index `0`. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np 
Pr = np.array([[1.72731864e+003, 0.00000000e+000],
       [0.00000000e+000, 1.24439020e+003]])

MaxPr=Pr.max(axis=1)
```

The expected output is

```
indices=[0,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use argmax()

```
Pr.argmax(axis=-1)
```